# Add post tag without post id

Tags: tags, terms

How can I add a new Tag without an post-id?

wp_set_post_tags() needs a Post-Id, but a client want import Post-Tags without assignment to a post (for choosing later into the posts).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i have found the solution. wp_insert_term() do this job perfectly ;)